# PHP - XSD schema validation error with unicode regular expression

Tags: php, xml, validation, xsd, schema

### Description:

When I try to validate XML file with given XSD schema containing Unicode regular 
expression, the function DOMDocument::schemaValidate return a validation error.
The XSD schema is W3C well formed and the validation pass with the other 
validation tools.
The problem doesn't occur if the XSD pattern is format like this (without square 
brackets):

```
<xsd:pattern value="\P{Ll}+"/>
```

PHP Version: 5.2.14
LibXml Version: 2.7.7

The previous pattern `[\P{Ll}]+` works correctly with `preg_match` function.

---

### Test script:

PHP Validation Code:

```
function libxml_display_errors()
{
   $errors = libxml_get_errors();

   print_r($errors);

   libxml_clear_errors();
}

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('test.xml');

if ( !$dom->schemaValidate('test.xsd') ) {
  echo "XML Error\n";
  libxml_display_errors();
} else {
  echo "XML ok\n";
}
```

---

### XSD Schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xsd:simpleType name="noLowerCase">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="[\P{Ll}]+"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:complexType name="DatiUtenteType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Cognome" type="noLowerCase"/>
            <xsd:element name="Nome" type="noLowerCase"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="DataExchangeFisso">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="DatiUtente" type="DatiUtenteType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="ListOfDataExchange">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="DataExchangeFisso" type="DataExchangeFisso" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

---

### XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListOfDataExchange>
  <DataExchangeFisso>
    <DatiUtente>
      <Cognome>FOO</Cognome>
      <Nome>BAR</Nome>
    </DatiUtente>
  </DataExchangeFisso>
</ListOfDataExchange>
```

---

### Expected result:

```
XML ok
```

---

### Actual result:

```
XML Error
Array
(
    [0] => LibXMLError Object
        (
            [level] => 2
            [code] => 1839
            [column] => 0
            [message] => Element 'Cognome': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'FOO' is not accepted by the pattern '[\P{Ll}]+'.
            [file] => /var/www/html/test.xml
            [line] => 5
        )

    [1] => LibXMLError Object
        (
            [level] => 2
            [code] => 1824
            [column] => 0
            [message] => Element 'Cognome': 'FOO' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'noLowerCase'.
            [file] => /var/www/html/test.xml
            [line] => 5
        )

    [2] => LibXMLError Object
        (
            [level] => 2
            [code] => 1839
            [column] => 0
            [message] => Element 'Nome': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'BAR' is not accepted by the pattern '[\P{Ll}]+'.
            [file] => /var/www/html/test.xml
            [line] => 6
        )

    [3] => LibXMLError Object
        (
            [level] => 2
            [code] => 1824
            [column] => 0
            [message] => Element 'Nome': 'BAR' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'noLowerCase'.
            [file] => /var/www/html/test.xml
            [line] => 6
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer to your question, but probably some clarification:

The regular expressions in XSD, even it might be similar to those with `preg_match`, are a different thing. So assuming that something has to work with XSD because it does work with `preg_match` is a guess, but not a strict test.

The [category<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#nt-catEsc) *Letters lowercase* with it's property `Ll` is defined by Unicode, the XSD library *should* support it.

Probably it's a problem with the negativity of the category, because it only says what not, but not what in a non-negative character class.

Try:

```
[^\p{Ll}]+
```

Comment: The XSD schema validation was given to me. I can't change it, otherwise I would be enough to remove the square brackets.

Comment: Then you need to fix the library components. I think it *should* work by specification, so the library is broken and needs fixing. It's free software, you can patch it and bring the fixes into the new version.

Comment: So do you think it's a php bug? I try to report it on the php site, but I don't have received any response yet.

Comment: I can not judge whether it is a bug or a feature. However, this most certainly is not PHP but the underlying library (probably XSLT). You should leave a link to your bug report with your question here as well.

Answer (score 1):

The schema is good, your schema processor has a bug or non-conformance. It's actually not unusual for schema processors to implement regex dialects somewhat different from the dialect defined in the XSD specification: lazy implementors just pass the regex straight through to their chosen library.

Comment: The problem is that validation also fails with other validators (for example Notepad++ XML tools), but is formally correct in according to the w3c specifications.